# Element tag needs to include in particular occurence using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to include the  tag inside the quotes using XSLT,

My Input XML is:

```
<text>
  <top>
    <p>Glucose builds up in your blood and your cells become starved for energy and can’t function properly.</p>
  </top>
  <bottom>
    <p>And, for some people, this may be all that is needed to successfully maintain target blood glucose levels.</p>
    <p>It doesn’t come in a pill form because it would get destroyed in the stomach during digestion.</p>
  </bottom>
</text>
```

XSL I used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:json="http://json.org/" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="80"/>
  <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" select="concat('((.{1,', $length, '})( |$))')"/>
  <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="' +&#10; '"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:break" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', regex-group(2), '&quot;')"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:param name="ser-params" as="element()">
    <output:serialization-parameters xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
      <output:method value="xml"/>
      <output:version value="1.0"/>
      <output:indent value="yes"/>
      <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes"/>
    </output:serialization-parameters>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="top">
    "top": <xsl:apply-templates/>,
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bottom">
    "bottom": <xsl:apply-templates/>,
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <span><xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space(string-join(text()/serialize(., $ser-params), '')))"/></span>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got the output as:

```
"top": <span>"Glucose builds up in your blood and your cells become" +
"starved for energy and can’t function properly."</span>,

"bottom": <span>"And, for some people, this may be all that is needed" +
"to successfully maintain target blood glucose levels."</span>

<span>"It doesn’t come in a pill form because it would get destroyed in" + 
"the stomach during digestion."</span>,
```

But i need output as:

```
"top": "<span>Glucose builds up in your blood and your cells become" +
"starved for energy and can’t function properly.</span>",

"bottom": "<span>And, for some people, this may be all that is needed" +
"to successfully maintain target blood glucose levels.</span>"

"<span>It doesn’t come in a pill form because it would get destroyed in" + 
"the stomach during digestion.</span>",
```

I want the  tag coming inside the quotes, Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have posted various variations on that topic already and you have received a lot of answers, do you understand any of them at all or why are you not able to adapt the solutions posted so far to further needs?

If you want to have serialized markup then you have already been shown how to use the serialize function to create that and if you first want to transform `p` elements to `span` elements then you simply need to do that which is a basic step in XSLT 2.0. So change

```
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <span><xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space(string-join(text()/serialize(., $ser-params), '')))"/></span>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="span">
        <span>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space(serialize($span, $ser-params)))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and of course use `<xsl:output method="text"/>` as already suggested several times and the output should be along the requested format, e.g.

```
        "top": 
        "<span>Glucose builds up in your blood and your cells become starved for energy" +
 "and can’t function properly.</span>"
    ,


        "bottom": 
        "<span>And, for some people, this may be all that is needed to successfully" +
 "maintain target blood glucose levels.</span>"
        "<span>It doesn’t come in a pill form because it would get destroyed in the" +
 "stomach during digestion.</span>"
    ,
```

(although I don't understand what that format is supposed to represent or achieve, it is certainly not JSON and would also not parse as Javascript).